# ES6 React componentWillMount not updating state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this component which should get some state onLoad with ajax.
Basic syntax:

```
import React from 'react';
import Header from './Header';
import FeedOwnerColumn from './FeedOwnerColumn';
import FeedColumnRight from './FeedColumnRight';
import ReportBug from './ReportBug';

class FeedApp extends React.Component{
  constructor(){
    super();

    this.addComment = this.addComment.bind(this);

  this.state = {
      ownerInfo: {},
      ownerDogs: [],
      ownerNotifications: [],
      ownerChat: {},
      posts: []
    };

  }
  componentWillMount(e){
     var that = this;
$.ajax({
  url: '/api/getUserInit',
  method: 'POST',
  data: {},
  success: function(response){
    console.log('Success: ', response);
    that.setState({
      ownerInfo: response.ownerInfo,
      ownerDogs: response.ownerDogs,
      ownerNotifications: response.ownerNotifications,
      ownerChat: response.ownerChat,
      posts: response.posts
    });
  },
  error: function(response){
    console.log('Error: ', response);
  }
});
  }
  addComment(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    //console.log(e.target.childNodes[0].value);

    var currTime = new Date();
    currTime = currTime.toLocaleString();

    var commentContent = e.target.childNodes[0].value;

    var key = Math.random();
    key = Math.round(key);

    var newComment = {
      id: key,
      name: "Peter Paprika",
      date: currTime,
      thumb_picture:"/imgs/user-q.jpg",
      profile_link: "/user/123",
      content: commentContent,
      like_amount: 0
    };

    //console.log(this.state.posts);

    var postsObj = this.state.posts;

    //console.log(postsObj[0].comments);

    var newComments = postsObj[0].comments;
    newComments.push(newComment);

    console.log(newComments);
    this.setState({posts: postsObj});

  }
  render() {
    return (
        <div className="clearfix wrapper">
          <Header />
          <FeedOwnerColumn />
          <FeedColumnRight posts={this.state.posts} addComment={this.addComment} />
          <ReportBug />
        </div>
    );
  }
}


export default FeedApp;
```

The first blank state gets set perfectly but unfortunately the ajax request in the componentWillMount method doesn't update the current state. (The response obj, is correct)

What am I doing wrong here ? :/

**EDIT** removed typos..

Comment: along with the `componentWillMoun` typo, you are using `that.state =`, though you need to use `that.setState()` to trigger a re-render.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have typo in `componentWillMount()` method. `t` is missing.

Secondly, according to [spec](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html), for ajax requests you should use `componentDidMount`.

**EDIT:** As David mentioned, You should use `this.setState()` method to mutate state.

Comment: Thanks, I just typed it out quickly since im am not on my personal computer - I will try it out with componentDidMount later today !

Comment: Also, `that.state = {` is not how you update state.  You should use `this.setState`.

Comment: You are right, in my rush to post that question before my shift starts I made these mistakes. Of course I am invoking the update of my status with this.setState({])

Comment: Hey thanks for asking - i can't really accept any answer because the problem was within something i didn't cover in the scope of this question. I am passing the state.posts further down to another component, and since the initial state was empty the maping function didnt know what to do since i didnt build any fallback for an empty posts state. Now everything is working fine

Answer (score 0):

you have to use `that.setState` function insted of `that.state`like

```
 that.setState({
      ownerInfo: response.ownerInfo,
      ownerDogs: response.ownerDogs,
      ownerNotifications: response.ownerNotifications,
      ownerChat: response.ownerChat,
      posts: response.posts
    });
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your participation - unfortunately this is what I am doing - I corrected my question and removed the typos which I inserted on a rush.